# Use enum as query argument in Graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, graphql-java-tools

What is the graphql syntax in SDL to use an enum as a query argument?

```
schema {
  query: Query
}
type Query {
    getWordsCountByLanguage (language: LanguageIso): [WordCount]
}
enum LanguageIso {
    AA
    AB
}
```

Parsing the above schema will throw an error that `Expected type 'language' to be a GraphQLInputType, but it wasn't!`

Defining an input type that includes an enum will result on a similar error.

It looks like there is no way of using an enum as a query argument in SDL.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug already reported [here](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-tools/issues/216)
The issue is with nested inputs (i.e., you have an input argument that contains an enum). If you directly pass the enum as argument as in my question should work.